# Google Cloud Platform - unified library

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've started new project in Java and wanted to deploy it on Google Cloud Platform ( not App Engine! ). I also would like to use some of the services/products provided by GCP: Datastore, PubSub etc.

I started with the Datastore and found a good library:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java

Then I decided to start using PubSub and found out that gcloud-java doesn't have anything related to PubSub.
Some of the supported libraries for Java PubSub are here:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/libraries

So, I just wanted to confirm ( because it seems too weird for me ), that Google doesn't have any unified Java library for their services? And I have no other way than to use two libraries ( with different strategies for managing credentials etc )?

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need first lib at all. You need just following:

```
compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.21.0"
compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub:v1-rev8-1.21.0"
```

And your code will be like:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential
      .fromStream(json)
      .createScoped(PubsubScopes.all());

// or on Google Cloud Platform
GoogleCredential credentials = GoogleCredential
      .getApplicationDefault(httpTransport, jsonFactory);

Pubsub pubsub = new Pubsub.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credentials)
      .build();
```